# Connecting to mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying an example tutorial for `AJAX` suggest from [here](http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Suggest_Tutorial-271_290_312.html). I found an issue in the `database.php` file. it containts a code segment like this.

```
function db_connect($server = 'localhost', $username = 'root', $password = '123', $database = 'db_ajax_suggest', $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;

    $$link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

    if ($$link) mysql_select_db($database);

    return $$link;
  }
```

My question is what is `$link = 'db_link'` in the code. I have worked with `php` before, but not a lot, I have not met a situation like this. All needed were $servername, $username, $password.

I am a `java` person more than `PHP`. In java I can use `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_ajax_suggest`.
But in this case, Hoe should set the database url?
Thank you!!

Comment: `$$link => ${'db_link'} => $db_link` Look for `variable variables` in php manual

Comment: your question is what is `$link = 'db_link'` doing there? thats just an argument, when not provided, `db_link` is used

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions, these are outdated!

Comment: @Ghost Is it not a must to provide it?

Comment: @user3892439 it is not a **must**. since you set a default value when not provided.

Comment: You dont have to provide. `Case:1` You provide the value. Its ok. `Case:2` You did not provide the value, then value will be equal to `$link = 'db_link'`

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Could you please explain it me bit more. In my case, username, password and databse name is provided. What is `'db_link'` doing here?

Comment: You shouldn't do a tutorial that suggests you using deprecated functions such as mysql_

Answer (score 0):

I think Only this much you needed to connect to your databases and work with your tables

```
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','123');
if (!$connect) {
die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('db_ajax_suggest',$connect);
```

and for fetching data from table

```
$query = " your query ";
mysql_query($query) or die('SQL ERROR:'.mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
```

and for DB

```
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());
```

and for your queries

```
mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
```

I find nothing better solution than this.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect` can have four paramter.

like this

```
mysql_connect($server,$user,$pwd,$newlink,$clientflag)
```

In my my first three you already know. You might have confusiong about $newlink and $clientflag

`$newlink`= Return bool value means TRUE or FALSE.

**Usage:** If the connection is called again in the script. now new conection will be created. if its set to `TRUE`.

`clientflag` The client_flags parameter can be a combination of the following constants: 128 (enable `LOAD DATA LOCAL handling), MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL, MYSQL_CLIENT_COMPRESS, MYSQL_CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE or MYSQL_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE`. Read the section about MySQL client constants for further information. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored. `**according to the php manual`**

Check these link for further info

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.constants.php#mysql.client-flags

Important Note: Please learn `mysqli` or `PDO`